# Запуск программы на Linux Ubuntu с помощью wine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, exe, wine

Я написал программу на с++ на Windows, теперь хочу запустить ее на Linux Ubuntu 16.04 с помощью wine. Но имею такую проблему.
Запускаю программу таким образом: `wine FirmWorkers.exe`
И получаю ошибки о том, что у меня не хватает нужных библиотек для открытия:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
`FirmWorkers.exe` - это не установочный файл, а программа.
Что посоветуете предпринять, чтобы запустить мою программу на Линуксе?

Comment: Очевидно, установить эти библиотеки. Судя по названиям библиотек, напрашивается запуск как минимум команды `winetricks vcrun2015` для их установки

Comment: Там же написано, что не хватает нужных `. dll`, установите в `Wine`, `MSVC` и `VCRuntime` ошибка должна исчезнуть.

Comment: @andreymal, благодарю. Но, моя версия winetricks предлагает установить `vs2010express`. Как Вы считаете, такая `.dll` подойдет?

Comment: @BorisMakhlin не подойдёт, потому что 140 в названии библиотеки это именно 2015. Что значит «предлагает»? Команда `winetricks vcrun2015` должна просто взять и установить без всяких там предлаганий.

Comment: @andreymal, на эту команду она ругается, говорит, что я использую 64-битный WINEPREFIX. А значит нужно писать команду такого вида: `winetricks [options] [command|verb|path-to-verb]`

Comment: @BorisMakhlin если программа 32-битная, то лучше использовать 32-битный WINEPREFIX. Если нет, то придётся страдать и устанавливать Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable вручную, скачав нужную 64-битную версию с сайта майкрософта

Comment: @andreymal, понял Вас. Спасибо большое. Переустановлю `wine` или же переделаю программу под 64-битную!

Comment: @BorisMakhlin нужно не «переустановить wine», а пересоздать WINEPREFIX командой вроде `WINEPREFIX=/путь/к/пустому/каталогу WINEARCH=win32 winecfg` (и потом соответственно устанавливать программу прописывая этот WINEPREFIX)

Comment: Или можно пересоздать стандартный WINEPREFIX, удалив его `rm -rf ~/.wine` (все программы в нём соответственно тоже удалятся) и потом пересоздав `WINEARCH=win32 winecfg` – тогда явно прописывать каждый раз WINEPREFIX будет не нужно (он будет стандартный `~/.wine`)

Comment: @andreymal, еще раз спасибо. Попробую и отпишусь

Comment: @andreymal, попробовал второй способ. Мне выпала настройка Wine Configuration. Тут по идее, можно добавить новые библиотеки, но в списке предложенных к сожалению нет либы `vc2015`. Или же нужно теперь принять эти параметры и просто попробовать установить эти библиотеки? Очень благодарен Вам за помощь

Comment: @BorisMakhlin Wine Configuration не нужен и можно закрыть (просто нужно было запустить хоть что-нибудь для инициализации WINEPREFIX), но теперь `winetricks vcrun2015` должен нормально отработать